# Parameter pack expansion with lambda in C++20

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, variadic-templates, c++20

**Case 1**:

Consider the following pack expansion in lambda `noexcept` specifier:

```
template <bool... B> 
auto g() {  
  ([]() noexcept(B) {}, ...);  
}
```

Clang and MSVC accept this code, but GCC [rejects](https://godbolt.org/z/sK7fxz) with:

```
error: expansion pattern '<lambda>' contains no parameter packs
```

Is this a valid code? Which Compiler should I trust?

**Case 2**:

Consider the following pack expansion in lambda `requires-clause`:

```
template <bool... B> 
auto g() {  
  ([](auto) requires(B) {}, ...);  
}
```

In this case, Clang and MSVC still accept this code, and GCC [rejects](https://godbolt.org/z/E1hzhd) it with the same error message. Is this just the same bug?

**Case 3**:

Consider the following pack expansion in the lambda template list:

```
template <typename... Args> 
void g(Args...) {
  ([]<Args>(){}, ...);  
}
```

This time three compiler [all reject](https://godbolt.org/z/6c71Ea) with the same error message:

```
expansion pattern '<lambda>' contains no parameter packs
```

Is there a difference compared to case 1? Or is this a common bug?

---

### Update:

GCC fixed case 1 in [99584](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99584), and MSVC fixed case 3 in [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/parameter-packs-not-expanded-in-lambda-template-li/1370220?from=email).

Comment: All 3 of those _should_ be accepted; if they don't, I'd consider it to be a bug in the standard.  They are each expressions, those expressions (at some level of recursion) contain a parameter pack, and those packs once expanded make sense.  However, specifying how parameter packs get expanded is a pain, and I can believe there are bugs in the standard that mandate them not working.  (of course, the `f(...)` call may be UB (or maybe not, I'd have to look at how empty lambdas and `...` interact), but that isn't important)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - Are you sure (that is correct) about the third case? I mean: what is `[]<Args>(){}`? Shouldn't be `[]<typename Args>(){}` that, in that case, define a new typename template parameter, shadows the function `Args` list and can't be unpacked?

Comment: @max66 non type template parameters

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - Uh... you're right.

Comment: Status update for this interesting question: **1**) Fixed in g++ 11.1. **2**) Not fixed in g++ 11.1, so not the same bug as in 1. **3**) Fixed in MSVC 19.29.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting exercise! Looking at the C++20 draft, the standard first distinguishes generic lambdas (7.5.5.5):

> A lambda is a *generic lambda* if the *lambda-expression* has any generic parameter type placeholders (9.2.8.5), or if the lambda has a *template-parameter-list*.
>
> ```cpp
> int i = [](int i, auto a) { return i; }(3, 4); // OK: a generic lambda
> int j = []<class T>(T t, int i) { return i; }(3, 4); // OK: a generic lambda
> ```

Therefore, case 1 has non-generic lambdas and 2 and 3 have generic lambdas. It does not differentiate between type and non-type template parameters, so I think I agree with Yakk - Adam Nevraumont, all three should be admissible.

Lambdas are represented by an unnamed, unique closure type having a function call operator (`operator()`) (template in case of a generic lambda), whose signature and constraints are determined by the lambda expression. The compiler could definitely satisfy each case with code resembling the following:

##### Case 1

```cpp
template<bool B>
struct closure {
    auto operator()() const noexcept(B) {}
};

template <bool... B> 
auto g() {  
  (closure<B>{}, ...);  
}
```

##### Case 2

```cpp
template<bool B>
struct closure {
    auto operator()(auto) const requires(B) {}
};

template <bool... B> 
auto g() {  
  (closure<B>{}, ...);  
}
```

##### Case 3

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct closure {
    template<T>
    auto operator()() const {}
};

template <typename... Args> 
void g(Args...) {
  (closure<Args>{}, ...);  
}
```

These all compile on my machine, currently with gcc 11.2.1.